# Операнд > невозможно применить к типу string и string

Tags: c#, строки

Я начинающий программист, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы не было ошибки ?

> Операнд > невозможно применить к типу string и string

```
for (int write = 0; write < arr.Length; write++)
{
    for (int sort = 0; sort < arr.Length - 1; sort++)
    {
        if (arr[sort] > arr[sort + 1])
        {
            temp = arr[sort + 1];
            arr[sort + 1] = arr[sort];
            arr[sort] = temp;
```

Comment: не сравнивать строки. как я понимаю - у вас массив строк, верно?

Comment: А что вы подразумеваете под `arr[sort] > arr[sort + 1]`? Вы сравниваете строки? или длину строки?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if (arr[sort] > arr[sort + 1])
> ```

```
if (String.CompareOrdinal(arr[sort], arr[sort + 1]) > 0)
```

Comment: При сортировке оно выдаёт мне не тот результат, который я хочу. Я использую BubbleSort

Comment: Значит используй то, что даёт тот результат, который ты хочешь.